# How to add edges between any two nodes on a condition?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, networkx

I have the following data set, variable "factor" denotes nodes, and variable "percent" is the attribute of the node. What I want to do is to create edges between all pairs of the nodes on the condition that the product of "percent" value of a pair is above a threshold.

For instance, suppose I set the threshold as 0.05, then the edges will only be created between A and B, B and C, and A and C.
Thanks.

Factor: A, B, C, D, ...
Percent: 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1

Comment: And how does your attempt of solving this problem look so far?

Comment: Please provide your input data as real python objects

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.